# How to not compile developer dependencies for production in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am working on a website which in production will communicate with the back end. The developers use dummy data to test the website during development, but this dummy data is being sent to the client even after a production build. I want to have this dummy data not be included in the final production build to reduce the bundle size.

I have considered using the file replacement feature of the angular compiler to be able to replace a development file with a production variant. I would like to avoid doing this if possible because this feature could be incredibly useful for substituting implementations at compile time without needing to hard code in replacements. Imagine if I had three or four different back end options to choose from and wanted to dynamically pick depending on a setting in my environment service. Once compiled, I would only want to have the one choice present.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
  useFactory: () => {
    const environment = inject(EnvironmentService);
    if (environment.dev) {
      return new DummyDataService();
    }
    return new HttpDataService(inject(HttpClient));
  }
})
export abstract class DataService() {
  public abstract getData(): Observable<string[]>;
}
```

```
export class HttpDataService implements DataService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getData(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>('/url');
  }
}
```

```
export class DummyDataService implements DataService {

  public getData(): Observable<string[]> {
    return of([
      'angular',
      'babel',
      'webpack',
      'gulp'
    ]);
  }
}
```

When I am using 'ng serve --prod' and have configured my environment to run in production. I would expect DummyDataService to not be included in the bundle, but when I inspect what's sent to the browser, DummyDataService is included in the bundle (the name is minified by the compiler, but the strings are still present).

Comment: Hi, are you using AOT for prod mode? There's a trick to build an array of imports (or declaration of providers) and only populate them in dev (or any needed) environment. But I was not able to make it work, or find any other solution, with AOT.

Comment: Hey João, I am using AOT in production mode but am not using the array of imports b/c I wanted to use Angular 6 style injection w/ the injectable decorator to support tree shaking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the dummy data in your front end, why not just host a different instance of your back end connected to a test database. That way you could use the Angular environment variables for exactly what they were intended?

I have a different environment file for each build which gets swapped out at compile time and injected into the app module to provide a different endpoint for information

Edit: Write unit tests to check the validity of your functionality

Comment: I am already using environment variables to be able to swap out my backend URL for instance and prepend that to requests in an HTTP interceptor, but my opinion is that you shouldn't need to rely on your backend when developing the frontend.

Comment: It's not very practical to try to write mock data services for every bit of functionality you are going to write, usually mock data is thrown away in a commercial application as soon as the uat database and services come online. Front end unit tests are more appropriate for what you need as you can mock out your objects and run tests against your functionality. This code won't be included in your angular build.